# Scala Slick Model with Optional Image column

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to add a column to an existing model that has an optional image, I am using Scala Slick with the Play Framework. What would be an example of storing a image with a Scala Slick model?

```
case class Complication(complicationId:Long,
vitalSignId:Long,
complication:String,definition:String,reason:String,
treatment:String,notes:String,
weblinks:String,upperlower:String)


object ComplicationDAO extends Table[Complication]("complications") with DbConn { 

  def complicationId = column[Long]("complication_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def vitalSignId = column[Long]("vital_sign_id") 
  def complication = column[String]("complication")
  def definition = column[String]("definition",O.DBType("varchar(4000)"))
  def reason = column[String]("reason",O.DBType("varchar(4000)"))
  def treatment = column[String]("treatment",O.DBType("varchar(4000)"))
  def notes = column[String]("notes",O.DBType("varchar(4000)")) 
  def weblinks = column[String]("weblinks")
  def upperlower = column[String]("upperlower") 
  def treatmentImage = ??? //here is where it needs to be defined! 
  def * = complicationId ~  vitalSignId ~ complication ~ definition ~ reason ~ treatment ~ notes ~ weblinks ~ upperlower<> (Complication, Complication.unapply _) 

  def autoInc = 
    vitalSignId ~ complication ~ definition ~ reason ~ 
    treatment ~ notes ~ weblinks ~ upperlower <>
    (NewComplication, NewComplication.unapply _) returning complicationId 

}
```

This is the model that I am trying to integrate an image into.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Have you tried using an `Option[Blob]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to actually store it into the DB you can use a url as `String` field, [this](https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBCakeExample.scala) example can get you started.

A table for pictures is used:

```
case class Picture(url: String, id: Option[Int] = None)

trait PictureComponent { this: Profile => //requires a Profile to be mixed in...
  import profile.simple._ //...to be able import profile.simple._ 

  class Pictures(tag: Tag) extends Table[Picture](tag, "PICTURES") {  

    def id = column[Option[Int]]("PIC_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def url = column[String]("PIC_URL", O.NotNull)

    def * = (url, id) <> (Picture.tupled, Picture.unapply)
  }

  val pictures = TableQuery[Pictures]

  private val picturesAutoInc = pictures returning pictures.map(_.id) into { case (p, id) => p.copy(id = id) }
  def insert(picture: Picture)(implicit session: Session): Picture = picturesAutoInc.insert(picture)
}
```

And then the user table as an external reference to the picture id:

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Option[Int])](tag, "USERS") {
  def id = column[Option[Int]]("USER_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("USER_NAME", O.NotNull)
  def pictureId = column[Int]("PIC_ID", O.NotNull)
  def * = (name, pictureId, id)
}
```

When inserting you can upload the image, store the url, retrieve the id and assign it to the `User` entity as external key. To make the external key column nullable you just have to use `[column[Option[Int]]` instead of `column[Int]`.

Otherwise you could use a `Blob` field as suggested in a comment, [there's a test inside the Slick library with JDBC](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/JdbcTypeTest.scala) that creates a table with a `Blob` field:

```
class T(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, Blob)](tag, "test3") {
  def id = column[Int]("id")
  def data = column[Blob]("data")
  def * = (id, data)
}

val ts = TableQuery[T]
```

And then to insert:

```
ts insert (1, new SerialBlob(Array[Byte](1,2,3)))
ts insert (2, new SerialBlob(Array[Byte](4,5)))
```

Then you can look into `java.io.serializable` on how to transform a file to bites before storing it into a `Blob`, this [link](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/jdbc/LOBS/BLOBFileExample.java) could help (ignore the sql parts).